# Is there a good Haskell library that parses RFC2822 mail payloads?

Tags: haskell, rfc2822

I'm looking for a Haskell library that can parse RFC2822 email bodies to extract the content, including attachments.

The only one I see is Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Rfc2822 from the hsemail package, but the author warns that it is not entirely up to par.

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hsemail/1.0/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Rfc2822.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `Codec.MIME.Parse` http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime-0.3.3.2?

Comment: Can you parse headers with this as well?

Comment: Sure. See `parseHeaders` and `parseMessage` functions in the [doc](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime-0.4.0.1/docs/Codec-MIME-Parse.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is also http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hsemail/1.7.2/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Rfc2822.html#g:11

Comment: But the user already knows that - it's clear from his post :)